# How can I modify the layout of Suggested Articles on Cases in Service Cloud Console

Tags: service-cloud-console, knowledge, page-layout

How can I modify the layout of Suggested Articles on Cases in Service cloud. Currently my suggested articles looks like this:

[image: Current Layout]

But I need the layout like this:

[image: Desired Layout]

Answer (score 2):

Well if your org is **Spring '17** enabled then you have an option to enable **Lightning Knowledge**. There is a good comparison chart between Lightning knowledge and Classic knowledge available [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_compare_classic_lightning.htm&type=0&language=en_us&release=206.7).

Check out the [**considerations**](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_knowledge_considerations.htm) before you turn Lightning Knowledge ON.

And if your org is not Spring '17 yet, then there is not much you can do, to the best of my knowledge, you wait.

Answer (score 2):

Following steps will help you:

> Setup -> Knowledge -> Knowledge Settings

[image: Knowledge Settings]

Since you are using Service cloud console, it will be good if you opt for Case feed based layout as opposed to Standard layout, so that look and feel will be uniform.

> In the Case feed based layout, click on `Layout Properties`.
>
> **Deselect** Knowledge Sidebar show in console.

[image: Layout Properties]

> In the Case feed based layout, click on `Custom Console Components`.
>
> **Select** Knowledge One as Right Sidebar Component

[image: Right Sidebar Component]

> In the App Configuration:
>
> **Select** Knowledge One  as `Console Component` (Just in case you want to use this)

[image: Console component]

> If you like to use Knowledge One, create a permission set and specify necessary permissions

[image: Knowledge Management Permissionset]

Comment: it is still not showing the console.

Comment: did you opt feed based layout?

Comment: yes, currently for me its showing suggested articles but I need knowledge

Comment: did you select "Knowledge One" in permission set?

Comment: I have two service console in my org but in one it is showing knowledge and another one it is showing suggested articles

Comment: I think you are missing somewhere, I have implemented this and working fine for me